# Essential singularity question

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm asked to classify the singularity at the indicated poing and to find the residue at that point for $$f(z)=z^ne^{1/z}$$ for $$z_0=0$$

Here's what I have: $$z^n(1+\frac1z+\frac1{2!z^2}+...)=z^n+\frac{z^n}{z}+\frac{z^n}{2!z^2}+...$$

Is it correct to say that I have a pole of infinite order which is $=z^n$?

Comment: Your Laurent series has infinitely many negative monomial terms  about $z_0$ so the singularity must be essential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The singularity is essential because there does not exist an $N$ such that

$$\lim_{z\to 0} z^N e^{1/z} = 0$$

The residue is simply the coefficient of $1/z$ in the Laurent expansion about $z=0$.  In this case, we need the $n+1$th term in the expansion of the $e^{1/z}$ term, which has coefficient $1/(n+1)!$; this is therefore the residue.

Comment: Ron, I don't see how you got $\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$. How do I conclude that through my laurent expansion shown above?

Comment: @User69127: What is the coefficient of $y^{n+1}$ in the expansion of $e^y$?

Comment: nevermind, I see why! Thanks Gordon!